# What is the design choice behind prepare_to_wait and finish_wait

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduling

As far as I know, In Linux, a kernel process should invoke prepare_to_wait like functions before calling the schedule() function to yield processor to others, which add itself to the waiting queue. And later, when a scheduler picks the process, it can continue its execution and invoke finish_wait function to remove itself from the waiting queue.

These two functions are usually utilized as below

```
prepare_to_wait(&wq, &__wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
if (condition) 
    schedule();
finish_wait(&wq, &__wait);
```

However, when the condition is not satisfied, it turns out that the process wastes its priceless CPU resource for putting itself to the waiting list and set the status, which of course involves costly spinlock. It seems that it would be reasonable to execute the prepare_to_wait function only when the condition is satisfied.

Or another alternative would be making the scheduler push the process into the waiting list and removing it when it invokes schedule function and return from the schedule function respectively. Why the kernel programmer has determined this way to make the programmer should invoke the combination of prepare_to_wait and finish_wait functions?

Comment: "It seems that it would be reasonable to execute the `prepare_to_wait` function only when the `condition` is satisfied." - No one prevents you from checking the `condition` before the function's call. But you still need to check the condition after the call, otherwise (due to race) you risk to put the process on a sleep with condition being true. (Usually `condition` is treated as the condition **for which we wait**, so `schedule()` is called only when the condition is false).

Comment: Indeed, the `wait_event` family check the condition first and only put the task on the wait queue if the condition is false.